# Correlation between code maintainability and development velocity

Tags: maintainability

Has anyone seen a clear correlation data between the code maintainability and a team's development velocity? Can anyone suggest an own experience, a research paper or any other information sources?

I have often experienced that long-lasting architectural problems, such as application modularity, migrating between dbs, are difficult to be refactored due to urgent demands from the business side. It is also difficult to argue from developer's view point how quantitatively such refactoring would enhance the development speed and longer-term benefits.

This question might not be suited for StackOverflow. I am happy to post this question somewhere else if someone could give me a suggestion just where.

Comment: This question is better suited in [programmers.SE]

Comment: @try-catch-finally thanks. It seems that on Programmers, [this post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/108403/is-there-a-correlation-between-code-complexity-and-developer-productivity) answers my question.